# Create a bunch of objects from files in a directory

Tags: python, python-object

I have made a class that I'm using to manipulate and work with my data.

```py
class DataSet():
    def __init__(self, path, label_names, ohe_names, random_state=420):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(path)
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.encodings = LabelEncoder() 
        self.scaler = StandardScaler()
```

and I want to create a new DataSet object for each file in a directory with the name of the DataSet being the file name.

I have this code so far.

```py
for file in os.listdir('data/'):
    name = file[:-4]
    path = 'data/'+file
```

Every `name`, for example 'fox', should be a new DataSet object with the name `name/fox`. How can I manage to do this?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you were happy with your own answer, you should also think about storing your `DataSet` instances in a container. I'm suggesting a `dict`:

```
frames = {}
for file in os.listdir('data/'):
    name = file[:-4]
    path = 'data/'+file
    frames[name] = DataSet(path)
print(frames)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will use your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

```py
for file in os.listdir('data/'):
    name = file[:-4]
    path = 'data/'+file
    exec("{} = DataSet('{}')".format(name, path))
```

Comment: btw it is better if you don't use `exec()`. So, what does this do for you exactly?

Comment: Why should I avoid using `exec()`? This imports all the .csv's in my data/ directory and creates a new DataSet object for each.

Comment: Ok, but where are those `DataSet` objects stored and how do you access them?

Comment: And if one of your files happens to be named `file`, `name`, `path`, etc., you're perfectly OK with it overwriting an actual variable in your program?

Comment: The class is essentially just a pandas dataframe. It has methods to do transformation and inverse transformation on the data. @jasonharper you're suggesting I use less generic variable names?